# Odd glitches occurring when trying to replace word in a file

Tags: c, string, file-io, scanf, text-parsing

This question is split into 3 parts : '**The Idea**', '**Assumptions**' and '**Code MRE**', so that you may help point my follies clearly, quickly and with least hassle, and also since, in descending order of frequency, most mistakes lie in the algorithm, the assumptions made during implementation and then in the actual code.

**The Idea :**

- Parse through file, at every blank space char (`' ' or '\t' or '\n' or '\0'`, increment `i`and store the blank space char in an int arr `EOW[i]` (so that even `\0` can be read).
- rewind `FILE *`. `int q =1;`
- for int `q` < `i`:
- `fscanf()` every word (word = sequence of chars seperated by blank space chars) and store to `buffer[]`.
- if `strcmp(buffer, target)==0` then `strcpy(buffer, replacement)`.
- `fprintf()` buffer followed immediately by char at `EOW[q]` to temp file.
- remove original file and rename temp file.

**Assumptions :**

- `fscanf(%s)` will scan and store character until encountering `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, and `'\0'` chars.
- `char` when stored to `int` arr is stored as its ASCII val, and element of `int` arr when stored to `char` is stored as its ASCII character.
- Usage & incrementation of counters `i` and `q` as well as usage for accessing array elements is correct, even if a tad bit twisted.

**Code M.R.E** :

```
int main(){
    char frep[261]; getf scanf("%260[^\n]",frep);eat(); // stores fname in frep[], clears stdin
    FILE * rep = fopen(frep,"r");FILE * tmp = fopen("Temp.Ctt","w");// opens file for reading and tmp for writing
    if(rep==NULL||tmp==NULL){
        perror("\nError ");fclose(rep);fclose(tmp);
    }
    else{
        char target[501]; printf("\n Target : "); scanf("%500s",target);eat(); // gets target word
        char replace[501]; printf("\n Replacement : "); scanf("%500[^\n]",replace);eat();// gets its replacement
        char buffer[501]; long long i=0; int EOW[100000];
        while(1){
            char ch = fgetc(rep);
            if(ch==EOF)
                break; // breaks loop if EOF reached
            else if(ch==' '||ch=='\t'||ch=='\n'||ch == '\0')
                i++;EOW[i]=ch;
        }
        rewind(rep);
        for(int q=1; q<i; q++){
                fscanf(rep,"%500s",buffer);
                if(strcmp(target,buffer)==0)
                    strcpy(buffer,replace);
                fprintf(tmp,"%s%c",buffer,EOW[q]);
        }
        fclose(rep);fclose(tmp);
        remove(frep); rename("Temp.Ctt",frep);
        printf("\nSucess.\n\nReplaced any instances of \"%s\" with \"%s\".\n",target,replace);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To give an example of what glitched I'm getting : supplying a file with `to be or not to be, that is the question.\n` and asking it to replace 'to' with '(to)' results in `(to)eberortnoto(to),be,tthatsisethe.` (**no** newline at the end ).

Comment: If `target` and `replacement` differ in size -- file corruption results.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin absolutely not. Thats precisely why I'm using `strcpy()` **not** `strcat()` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    else if(ch==' '||ch=='\t'||ch=='\n'||ch == '\0')
        i++;EOW[i]=ch;
```

This is missing the `{ ... }` braces, causing `EOW[i]=ch;` to fall *outside* the `else if`.

```
    for(int q=1; q<i; q++){
```

Make that `q <= i` otherwise it's skipping over the last element, given how `EOW` is numbered.

`int EOW[100000];`

Unrelated, but you can make that `char EOW` since there is no good reason for it to be an `int`.

Comment: Thanks dxiv. I had figured out the first point myself, but it was then just replacing **every** word with the replacement, which I *no clue* why. I looked at your suggestion on `q` and then just made it `for( int q=0; q<I;q++)` and instead just used `EOW[q+1]`, and made `EOW[]` a char arr, since you had a good point, and now , it's working... I have no idea why, but its not replacing everything anymore ...